# Need help writing an htaccess, in cpanel hosting that helps me access my symfony 2 application without any /web or folder names in url

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite, cpanel

I have a c-panel shared hosting. Now, the docroot for the `sitename.com` resides at `public_html` folder. Say, I have a symfony application installed in the same. So, the web folder for my symfony application is at `public_html/symfony/web/`. If I want to try it, I should hit `sitename.com/symfony/web/app_dev.php`.

Here's the tricky part: I am trying to use htaccess somehow to get `sitename.com/hi` to invoke `sitename.com/symfony/web/app_dev.php/hi` internally. The constraints are, I cannot modify my `httpd-vhosts.conf` to update my hosting directory. It might not be a practical thought, still, would love to figure out this, just as some food for thoughts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your public_html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit `.htaccess` in `public_html` folder and add `rewrite` directives to  pointing your request to wanted foder `/symfony/web/` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !symfony/web/
RewriteRule (.*) /symfony/web/$1 [L]

DirectoryIndex app.php
```

If you are using `/symfony/web/app.php` as front controller don't forget to add directive `DirectoryIndex`.